# Creating multidimensional array and removing empty categories

Tags: php, arrays

I have a single-dimensional array of categories; some of which are children of other categories, and some of which contain 'elements'. I need to turn it into a multidimensional array, and remove any categories which have no elements in them or any of their children (or children's children...).

I have the following array:

```
$category_array = array(

    1 => array(
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'parentcat' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
    ),

    4 => array(
        'elementcount' => 0,
        'parentcat' => 1,
        'depth' => 2
    ),

    8 => array(
        'elementcount' => 0,
        'parentcat' => 4,
        'depth' => 3
    ),

    9 => array(
        'elementcount' => 2,
        'parentcat' => 4,
        'depth' => 3
    ),

    11 => array(
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'parentcat' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
    ),

    12 => array(
        'elementcount' => 0,
        'parentcat' => 11,
        'depth' => 2
    ),

    21 => array(
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'parentcat' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
    )

);
```

and I need the following array:

```
$multidimensional_array = array(

    1 => array(
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'children' => array(
            4 => array(
                'elementcount' => 0,
                'children' => array(
                    9 => array(
                        'elementcount' => 2
                    )
                )
            )        
        )
    ),

    11 => array(
        'elementcount' => 3,
    ),

    21 => array(
        'elementcount' => 3,
    )

);
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You'd need some loops. Anything you've tried so far ?

Comment: I get as far as using about three foreach loops, but I'm having a bit of a scatterbrain day and my brain is just refusing to work...

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you take a good walk outside and then give it another try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an approach:

```
<?php

$input = [
    1 => [
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'parentcat' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
    ],
    4 => [
        'elementcount' => 0,
        'parentcat' => 1,
        'depth' => 2
    ],
    8 => [
        'elementcount' => 0,
        'parentcat' => 4,
        'depth' => 3
    ],
    9 => [
        'elementcount' => 2,
        'parentcat' => 4,
        'depth' => 3
    ],
    11 => [
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'parentcat' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
    ],
    12 => [
        'elementcount' => 0,
        'parentcat' => 11,
        'depth' => 2
    ],
    21 => [
        'elementcount' => 3,
        'parentcat' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
    ]
];

$maxDepth = max(array_column($input, 'depth'));

// handle elements from higher to lower depth
for ($d = $maxDepth; $d >= 0; $d--) {

  array_walk($input, function(&$entry, $index) use (&$input, $d) {
    if (isset($entry['depth']) && $entry['depth'] == $d) {

      // omit entries without elements or elements in children
      if ($entry['elementcount'] < 1 && empty($entry['children'])) {
        unset($input[$index]);

      // handle as child entry of a parent entry
      } else if (array_key_exists($entry['parentcat'], $input)) {
        $input[$entry['parentcat']]['children'][$index] = [
          'elementcount' => $entry['elementcount'],
          'children' => isset($entry['children']) ? $entry['children'] : []
        ];
      unset($input[$index]);

      // handle as ordinary entry
      } else {
        $input[$index] = [
          'elementcount' => $entry['elementcount'],
          'children' => isset($entry['children']) ? $entry['children'] : []
        ];
      }
    }
  });

}

print_r($input);
```

The strategy:

- handle higher depths first so that the order of input elements does not matter
- for each element check if the parent exists, if so stuff it in there
- redefine all handled elements

The obvious output is:

```
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [elementcount] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [elementcount] => 0
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [9] => Array
                                        (
                                            [elementcount] => 2
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [elementcount] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [21] => Array
        (
            [elementcount] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

I took the liberty to create a slightly modified result compared to your suggestion:

The 'children' property *always* exists as an array. That makes the usage of the result easier and more robust later on. I'd say that in general all elements inside a structure should have identical structure themselves *if possible* ...

Comment: This is good, but it still contains categories 8 and 12. I'd prefer for them to not be in the array at all

Comment: Ah, OK, I missed that, indeed. I updated the answer to honor that condition too...

Comment: Would this work? The logic to omit entries checks if the element count is less than one, (which makes sense if it has no children) and if the value of the 'children' key is empty, which, as no 'children' keys exist in the array until later, will always be true... unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: I'd argue that an entry can be dropped if it has a zero element count _unless_ it has children. Since those children can only survive if they themselves have an element count this makes sure that the element does _not_ get dropped if it does not have an element count itself, but a child with an element count. That is how I understood the question. Keep in mind the order of processing: from higher depth to lower depth. So the children are processed _first_ ...

Comment: You're quite right; as the deepest children are processed first, it does make sense. Thanks, marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isParent($id, $list) : bool {
    foreach($list as $item) {
        if ($item['parentcat'] === $id) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function buildLevel($parent, $catsByParent) : array {
    $result = $catsByParent[$parent] ?? [];

    foreach($result as $id => $cat) {
        if (isset($catsByParent[$id])) {
            $result[$id]['children'] = buildLevel($id, $catsByParent);
            unset($catsByParent[$id]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

// Filter out empty categories
$cats = array_filter(
    $category_array,
    function($cat, $id) use($category_array) {
        return $cat['elementcount']>0 || isParent($id, $category_array);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);

$catsByParent = [];
// Build cats list keyed by parentcat
foreach($cats as $id => $cat) {
    $parent = $cat['parentcat'];
    unset($cat['parentcat'], $cat['depth']);
    $catsByParent[$parent] = ($catsByParent[$parent] ?? []) + [$id => $cat];
}

// Build result
$multidimensional_array = buildLevel(0, $catsByParent);

print_r($multidimensional_array);
```

First one filters out empty elements, i.e "categories which have no elements in them or any of their children". (children's children requirement sounds strange, wouldn't that be "any of their children" one level further down?)

Then the remaining categories are grouped/sorted by parentcat, aka "level id", to make the list workable :).

Then that list is traversed, starting with level id 0 at the top, and recursively processed(the children) as deep down as needed.